Finding longest substring without repeating characters
I'm trying to solve LeetCode 3: Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters.
I'm implementing the Sliding Window method, which consists of using a left and a right pointer to contract and expand the window. I'm also using a std::set to store the characters of the string.
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>    //for std::max()


//Sliding window
int lengthOfLongestSubstring(std::string s)
{
    std::set<char> charSet;       
    int length = s.size();
    int left = 0;
    int right;
    int longest = 0;      //value we should return


    for(right = 0; right < length; right++) 
    {
        char c = s[right];  //get each element of the string


        //if character already exist in the set
        while (charSet.count(c)) //while we found a character that is a duplicate, we'll contract the window by increase the left pointer + 1
        {
            charSet.erase(s[left]);      //removing the element where left pointer is pointing at
            left += 1;                      //increase the left pointer
        }

        charSet.insert(c); //store the current element into the set

        int w = left - right + 1;           //calculate window length
        longest = std::max(longest, w);     //update longest with longest current window length
    }

    return longest;

}


int main()
{
    std::string s{"abcabcbb"};

    std::cout << lengthOfLongestSubstring(s);

    return 0;
}

Output:
2

The correct output should be 3.

I would use: stdarray<size_t, 128> lastPosCharSeen; and single loop yo make it fast.

OT: Unless you need the elements in the set to be ordered, use std::unordered_set.

int w = left - right + 1; clearly that should be int w = right - left + 1;. If took me a couple of minutes to find that using a debugger. Perhaps you should also learn how to debug?

As for your problem, have you tried to debug your code? Like for example to use a debugger to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values?

Yes sorry, I'm pretty new at programming, I'm still learning to use the debugger properly. But fixing the formula fixed the problem, now it works, thanks

Well, just printing w within the loop was enough to pinpoint the problem.  What we used to call "printf debugging" is still effective.

My solution (beat 90.99% runtime, and beat 100% memory): https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/solutions/5894723/a-jumping-and-expanding-sliding-window Leetcode is a site you go to after you've learned how to code. I do not recommend it at all for learning to code.

I am also finding this "new at programming" line to be dubious given 8K rep, an 8 year old account, and python as the top tag. Maybe we've got a hijacked account.

dont include the answer in the question. If you want you can write an answer below in the answer section. Adding the solution to your question renders the question obsolete. Consider that we aim to answer questions. In your post there is actually no quesiton. You show some code, say there is a problem, then present the fix. So what? What is your question? one wonders when reading this. I reverted your update, you can post it as answer

Your code fails on simple test case "ab": https://godbolt.org/z/dGx7GME89

Basically your code have silly mistake in this line:
int w = left - right + 1;           //calculate window length

https://godbolt.org/z/nPs3GvfqE
Correcting that to:
int w = right - left + 1;           //calculate window length

and tests are passing: https://godbolt.org/z/sfqzvhbc8
Anyway there is better faster solution, with this I've got 0 time (100% faster then others) and using less memory then 93.55% of other submissions.

I like this solution a lot. I'm surprised I didn't think to use std::array to hold the character locations. I am surprised that Leetcode accepts std::ranges; they must have updated their toolchain in the last year or so.
